# How can I use Dynamic feature to find an item by value

Tags: blueprism

I have a table that has many random generated items in it. I need to choose one. Loading the table in a collection, then looping into it is so much work and time. Is there a way to use Dynamic feature in blueprism to achieve the same work faster and in less steps?

Answer (score -1):

A combination of wildcard for the ID and dynamic features for value or matching index will do the trick. In action, add a navigate stage, choose the item and pass in the value or number for matching index in param.